# AJAX call to a web service returns [object Object]

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, web-services

I am trying to call a webservice(URL) using jQuery and AJAX, the response from the webservice is a plain string, username and password are query parameters in webservice, this is the code I have:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $(".signup").click(function(){
            $.ajax({  
           type: "GET",  
           url: "http://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/UserManagement/rest/user_details/sign_in/?username=saurabh&password=hi", 
           dataType: "text",           
           success: function(resp){  
             // we have the response
             alert(resp);  
           },  
           error: function(e){  
             alert('Error121212: ' + e);  
           }  
         });
        });
    });
    </script>
```

I am getting error [object Object]

Why am I facing this error? Is there any error in the code or some thing more precise  needsto be focused?Please help

Comment: try alert(JSON.parse(resp));

Comment: @StaticVoid — "the response from the webservice is a plain string" - so why would JSON.parse help?

Comment: Oh I see, you're hitting the error block. Quentin's response below should allow you to see the error properly.

Comment: @OP do you have any question to ask? I don't see any question asked.

Answer (score 1):

Look at [the documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/):

> **error**
>   Type: Function( jqXHR jqXHR, String textStatus, String errorThrown )

You are using the first argument (`error: function(e){  alert('Error121212: ' + e);`) so are trying to convert a jQuery XMLHttpRequest object to a string. It doesn't convert cleanly, so you get the standard result of translating a generic object to a string.

Look at the third argument instead.

Also consider examining the arguments are objects:

- Without using the `+` operator (which will convert them to a string when the LHS is a string)
- Without using `alert` (which will convert them to a string).

Such:

```
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){  
    alert("There was an error. Look in the browser's JS console for details.");  
    console.log(jqXHR);
    console.log(textStatus);
    console.log(errorThrown);
}
```

---

You should probably check the JS console anyway, as it will probably give you a cross-origin error message. (Solutions for which are easily discoverable with a search engine).

Comment: As this seems OP has not asked any question.

Comment: This is what I am getting in JS console: XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://ec2-xx-xxx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:8080/UserManagement/rest/user_details/sign_in/?username=sau752&password=hi. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1' is therefore not allowed access. What needs to be done for this????

Comment: What happens when you type `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource` into a search engine?